# What is a word for someone speaking out of turn?

Tags: single-word-requests

Okay, so I was wondering if there is a singular word for when someone is speaking out of turn. Like when someone answers a question not asked of them.
Example:

> Kim: (speaking to Ryan) Do you know what time it is?
>
> Jasper: 1pm

Does anyone know what Jasper would be called, due to speaking out of turn?

Example sentence:

> Jasper is a *{word}*, always answering questions even when they're directed at someone else.

Comment: Perhaps an *intruder*?

Comment: Busybody? Butter-in? (<= This would be a very [Seinfeld-esque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinfeld#Catchphrases) word, meaning that it's not a real word, but could be used informally and everyone would understand what you mean.) And a "busybody" is not necessarily one who always answers questions directed at other people, but these sorts of people could also be seen as meddling (as people who answer others' questions sometimes may be).

Comment: **jump the gun** :
to do something before it should be done *Jasper  always jumps the gun :answering questions even when they're directed at someone else.*
Etymology: based on the literal meaning of jump the gun (to begin to run a race before the gun that signals the start has been shot)

Answer (score 5):

In that context, Jasper may be called an interjector.

> **interject** *verb*
> to throw in between or among other things
> *interject a remark*
> (interjector *noun*)
> [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interjector)
>
> **interjector** One who interjects
> [- wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interjector)

Here's an example of the use of this term:

> An interjector whose interjection is taken up by the member speaking and is misquoted has no right to take a point of misrepresentation, for the interjector has not been misquoted as to a part of a speech, only to an interjection.
> [- Page 146, Parliamentary Practice in New Zealand](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=0qIqAAAAYAAJ&q=%22interjector%22&dq=%22interjector%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_6OPkPTTAhVEE7wKHc4LDgE4HhDoAQhOMAg)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Jasper is "interrupting."